# a list of numbers while stripping everything but numbers

Tags: php, preg-replace, explode

I have a list of numbers like this:

```
123-4-5679 tha
546-5465-7 dsf
98-4564-64 ds8
```

I want to explode into it's own value while striping everything but the numbers. I am doing but it seems to keep everything but it does give me a value per line

```
$pn = preg_replace("/\r/", "\n", preg_replace("/\r\n/", "\n", $_POST['phone']));
$phone_numbers = explode("\n", $pn);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also do it with one quick line in regex.

```
preg_match_all(":([0-9-]+):mi", $_POST["phone"], $match);
```

Here's an [example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/63d670a2ce5ab3fcdfe2c499f5d17c8516617218)

**Edit:** To remove hyphens iterate through the results and replace the hyphens with an empty string

```
preg_match_all(":([0-9-]+):mi", $_POST["phone"], $matches);

// remove extra match array
$matches = array_shift($matches);

foreach( $matches as & $match )
{
   $match = preg_replace(":-:", "", $match);
}
```

Updated [example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4e2b7b77b907880fa9e2d3570edb4c5032046cd3)

Comment: Or `$numbers = preg_match_all(":([\d-]+):", $phone, $m) ? $m[0] : [];
`

Comment: i like this one, but how do I remove the hypens as well?

Answer (score 1):

I'd strip everything but digits and newlines:

```
$cleaned = preg_replace("/[^0-9\n]/", "", $_POST['phone']);
```

And then `explode` it:

```
$numbers = explode("\n", $cleaned);
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep all numbers, match everything else but the line-separators:

```
~(?![\d-]+).*~
```

Usage in PHP to replace each match with an empty string

```
$numbers = preg_replace("~(?![\d-]+).*~", '', $phone);
```

Result:

```
123-4-5679
546-5465-7
98-4564-64
```

Answer (score -2):

Ok am i missing somethins?

```
$phone = explode(' ', $_POST['phone']);
$phone_number = $phone[0];
```

Isn't this working?

Comment: No he wants to strip everything but the numbers.